# what is the (ev=none) argument?

Tags: python

What is the `(ev=none)` argument in the below code?

```
// This program detects shock and responds by turning an LED on. 

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

ShockPin = 11
LedPin   = 12

Led_status = 1

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)       
    GPIO.setup(LedPin, GPIO.OUT)   
    GPIO.setup(ShockPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH) 
def swLed(ev=None):
    global Led_status
    Led_status = not Led_status
    GPIO.output(LedPin, Led_status)  
    print "led: " + ("on" if Led_status else "off")

def loop():
    GPIO.add_event_detect(ShockPin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=swLed, bouncetime=200)
    while True:
        pass   

def destroy():
    GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.LOW)      # led off
    GPIO.cleanup()                     # Release resource

if __name__ == '__main__':     # Program start from here
    setup()
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  
        destroy()
```

Comment: That's a default parameter. If `ev` is not passed in, the value defaults to `None`. Edit: `ev` isn't even used in that function so it doesn't even matter and GC will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you define a new function you can assign default values to your function's parameters. If you choose to do so, you will do it by using the syntax you just saw:

```
def my_func(arg_1, arg_2="some_value"):
    print(arg_1, arg_2)
```

Whenever you choose to call your new function, you can call it with both parameters

```
my_func('a', 'b')
```

Or, if you default the last parameter to a value, you can call it with only the first parameter and the second will always take the default value.

```
my_func('a')
```

In this case, the second parameter will just get to be "some_value".

Some more fun with default values here: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

TL;DR version: in your case whoever wrote that code wants to default "ev" to None. Don't know why, since the function's only parameter is never used in the actual function code.

Comment: Thank for the answer. But if I remove the arguement (ev=none), and run the program, it shows an error message: swled() takes no arguement (1 given). Is that because I am using this function in add_event_detect callback?

Comment: Taken from here: http://tieske.github.io/rpi-gpio/modules/GPIO.html#add_event_detect: Your swLed function is actually a callback function and it needs one input parameter. Which should be the channel number. And you always default it to None probably in order to avoid costly mistakes like the first example in the link in my answer.